# Is it necessary to learn JavaScript Language for Oracle forms and Reports 11G

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I would like to know: is it necessary to learn the JavaScript language in Oracle forms and reports?

Comment: No it is not necessary, but it won't hurt, because you can integrate javascripts to Forms. But that is not a place to ask these kind of questions, if you have problems with Forms or Reports, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary in general, no - you do not need to write any Javascript for a Forms applicaiton.

However it is **possible** to integrate Javascript into a Forms application - and to do that you would need to know some Javascript.